# Loop through file and for each entry create condition

Tags: java, loops, dynamic, foreach, conditional-statements

I would like to loop through a file (YAML) that contains entries.
For each of the entries stored in file I would like to create condition, to have it dynamic based on the entries. To have it more complicated when the entry is > 1 it will add it as else if

Let's have YAML file

```
Entries:
- 9-5
- 5-3
- 3-1
```

Looping

```
for(String fileEntry : file.getStringList("File.Entries")) {
}
```

Expected result

```
if (something > 9)
{
} else if (something < 9 && something > 5)
{
} else if (something < 5 && something > 3)
{
} else if (something < 3 && something > 1)
{
} else if (something < 1)
{
}
```

**something** is just int value stored in the class to compare with within the conditions.

**else if** included as noted before

I don't know honestly how to build these conditions upon loop. Is it even possible?

Please, any help?

Comment: I think you'll need to add more detail to your question to get a good answer. What would each of these conditions do? How would the program decide that? What should it do if there are gaps in the ranges, or if the ranges are in a different order?

Comment: Can you provide code where you've made an attempt to read the file?